# Transforming data to screen coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas

I would like to transform data to screen coordinates in javascript using a function. The function has to look like this:

```
function createTransform(domain, range){
    // domain is a two-element array of the domain’s bounds
    // range is a two-element array of the range’s bounds
    // implement the actual calculation here
    var alpha = ...;
    var beta = ...;
    return function(x){
        return alpha * x + beta;
    };
}

// to use this for instance:
var tranform = createTransform([10, 20], [10, 20]);
console.log(transform(15));  // should log 15
```

I have been looking at this for hours but still do not understand it.

Comment: Comments are written with slashes not backslashes, should have been `//`

Comment: Comments aside, what's the actual question?  You have a function (`createTransform`) that takes a domain and range, and returns an anonymous function.  When you call that function with an input, it gives you a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to take your data values and scale them to fit onto the screen. It uses a mapping function to calculate a desired screen value given a specific data value.

```
function mapRange(value, dataLow, dataHigh, screenLow, screenHigh) {
    return screenLow +
         (value - dataLow) * (screenHigh - screenLow) / (dataHigh - dataLow);
}
```

**How it works**

At its essence, you must **scale** the incoming data range to fit inside the any range of  screen coordinates  that are dedicated to displaying the data.

You are scaling **one range** into **another range**. You might think of the scaling factor as a percentage of the data range versus the screen range.

```
// calculate the scaling factor required to fit the data inside the screen
var scalingFactor = screenRange / dataRange;
```

All data points fall inside the data range which is calculated like this:

```
// calculate the min/max range of all data
var dataRange= maximumDataValue – minimumDataValue;
```

All screen coordinates fall inside the screen range which is calculated like this:

```
// calculate the min/max range of all screen coordinates
//     that are dedicated to displaying the data
var screenRange = maximumScreenCoordinateValue – minimumScreenCoordinateValue;
```

If you want to use the full screen then the `screenRange` becomes the screen width.

The next step is to calculate the relative position of a specific data-point inside the full data range:

```
// calculate any one specified data-point's relative position within
// the full data range
var thisDatumPositionInDataRange = thisDataValue – minimumDataValue;
```

Finally, use the `scalingFactor` to map (==scale) a specific data value onto the available screen coordinate.

```
// calculate the screen coordinate where the specified dataum
//    will be displayed
var screenCoordinate = minimumScreenValue + thisDatumPositionInDataRange * scalingFactor;
```

In words, this calculation means:

• Start at the minimum (==leftmost) screen coordinate.

• Move righward on the screen by the specified datum’s relative position (in its data range) scaled by the `scalingFactor`.

**Here's example annotated code:**

```
// supply a data value (value)
// and supply the min & max of the datum and the screen size
// return value mapped to fit onto the screen
function mapRange(value, dataLow, dataHigh, screenLow, screenHigh) {
    return screenLow + (screenHigh - screenLow) * (value - dataLow) / (dataHigh - dataLow);
}

// calculate the max & min of a given array
function calcDataMinMax(a){
    var min=1000000;
    var max=-1000000;
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        var value=a[i];
        if(value<min){min=value;}
        if(value>max){max=value;}
    }
    return({min:min,max:max});
}

// Usage:

// example data
var data=[5,10,-3,20,0,2];

// example screen width
var screenWidthMin=0;
var screenWidthMax=640;

// calc the min and max of values in your data
var dataRange=calcDataMinMax(data);

// map the data value 8 to fit onto the screenWidth
var map8=mapRange(8,dataRange.min,dataRange.max,0,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createTransform(domain, range) {

  var domain_min = domain[0];
  var domain_max = domain[1];
  var range_min = range[0];
  var range_max = range[1];

  var beta = (range_max / domain_max - range_min / domain_min) * (domain_min * domain_max) / (domain_min - domain_max);

  var alpha = (range_min - beta) / domain_min;

  return function(x) {
    return alpha * x + beta;
  };
}
```

```js
function createTransform(domain, range) {

  var domain_min = domain[0];
  var domain_max = domain[1];
  var range_min = range[0];
  var range_max = range[1];

  var beta = (range_max / domain_max - range_min / domain_min) * (domain_min * domain_max) / (domain_min - domain_max);

  var alpha = (range_min - beta) / domain_min;

  return function(x) {
    return alpha * x + beta;
  };
}

var calculateButton = document.querySelector('.calculate');
var domain_minInput = document.querySelector('.domain_min');
var domain_maxInput = document.querySelector('.domain_max');
var range_minInput = document.querySelector('.range_min');
var range_maxInput = document.querySelector('.range_max');
var xInput = document.querySelector('.x');
var resultBox = document.querySelector('.result');


calculateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var domain_min = parseInt(domain_minInput.value);
  var domain_max = parseInt(domain_maxInput.value);
  var range_min = parseInt(range_minInput.value);
  var range_max = parseInt(range_maxInput.value);
  var x = parseInt(xInput.value);
  var transform = createTransform([domain_min, domain_max], [range_min, range_max]);
  resultBox.textContent = transform(x);
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
domain_min
<input class="domain_min">domain_max
<input class="domain_max">range_min
<input class="range_min">range_max
<input class="range_max">x
<input class="x">
<button class="calculate">Calculate</button>
<h3>result:</h3>
<div class="result"></div>
```