# Zoom to fit, canvas, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I got a dataset that varies alot, sometimes the points is `[-34343, 343434]` and sometimes it's `[10, 20]`.

Is there anyway to "zoom to fit" so the content of a canvas is always fitting the data?

I've looked at `transform` but when I zoom in, the line's get thicker. I want the lines to always be same width regardless of the zoom.

https://jsfiddle.net/s2cfp34n/

Comment: You've chosen wrong tool. Canvas is raster-based and isn't intended for zoom. Use [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) instead. It is a right choice for use with datasets.

Comment: @hindmost. Nope :-) Canvas draws its paths as vectors and renders those vectors onto a bitmap (rasterized). SVG does exactly the same thing(!), but SVG also "remembers" what it drew. Hence, when resizing SVG you don't have to reissue the drawing commands like you must for canvas.

Comment: See this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845018/transforming-data-to-screen-coordinates/29852658#29852658) to see how to fit wide-ranging data onto the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

To scale while keeping the rendering lines the same.

First find the extent of the data so that you end up with the pixel Width and Height

```
// what ever data format you have do what you need to fine width and height
var dataWidth = Math.max(...data.x)-Math.min(...data.x);
var dataHeight = Math.max(...data.y)-Math.min(...data.y);
```

You also need the top left corner coordinate of the data

```
var dataX = Math.min(...data.x);
var dataY = Math.min(...data.y);
```

Then find the scale that fits all the data use the smallest scale of the two scales you get by dividing the canvas size by the data size

```
var scale = Math.min(canvas.width / dataWidth, canvas.height / dataHeight);
```

Now to calculate where the origin needs to be so the top left data position is touching at least one edge of the canvas

```
originX = (canvas.width / 2) - ((dataWidth / 2) + dataX) * scale;
originY = (canvas.height / 2) - ((dataHeight / 2) + dataY) * scale;
```

So you now have all the data you need to create the transformation matrix.

```
ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,originX,originY);
```

There are two ways to render the lines at a fixed width.

Get the inverse scale and multiply the desired line width with it

```
var invScale = 1 / scale;
ctx.lineWidth = 2 * invScale; // the line width will always be 2 pixels
ctx.lineWidth = 1 * invScale; // the line width will always be 1 pixels
... etc
```

Or a nice trick is to reset the transform after you create the path but before you render the stroke.

Set the scaled transform and create the path

```
ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,originX,originY);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(data[0].x,data]0].y);
ctx.lineTo(data[1].x,data]1].y);
... and so on
```

Until you have created all the path and before you call stroke reset the transform to the default scale. The renderer will use the lineWidth at the current transforms, while the path remains at the scale you added them with

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
ctx.lineWidth = 2; // two pixels
ctx.stroke();
```

This is useful if you want to create oval shapes from the arc function, or do any non uniform scaling without getting inconsistent line widths.